# Is my programming for loop equivalent correct if I want to state this in mathematical terms?

Tags: summation

Would the mathematical equivalent for this for loop:

```
var runningTotal = 0;
for( i = 12; i >= 2; i-- )
{
    runningTotal += i;
}
```

be:

$$
\text{runningTotal} = \sum_{i=12}^{i=2} f(i)
$$

Or does something need to be stated in the f(i) to state "add i12 to i11 to i10..."

Comment: Is $f(i)=i$? Your loop is computing $\sum_{i=2}^{12} i$

Comment: So the expression "i" after the "sum of", means "add what i was to the last version of me"? For some reason I thought that needed to be expressed as a function "f". I also thought I might need i + i(subi + 1). Thank you for your help. Can you put it as the answer so i can mark it for you and others :) . I also noticed you have put the 12 at the top. Considering it's the same value, is that just a convention to put highest over smallest if the output is the same?

Comment: Yes, $12+11+10+9+8+7+6+5+4+3+2 = 2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10+11+12$.  The order we do addition of numbers is irrelevant (mathematically).  We say addition is **commutative** (and **associative**).  In the $\sum$ notation, the convention is that the smallest value of the index is on the bottom, the largest on the top.

Comment: I think I may have figured out the sum of notation. It's obvious of course - "It's saying that it's the sum of all of the "i"s from 2 - 12. Thanks guys n gals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, you could just write $runningTotal = 77$

or you could write $\sum_{i=2}^{12}i$ or $\frac{(12+2)(12-2+1)}{2}$

But a recursive definition seems more fitting to me:

$S_{12} = 12$

$S_{i-1} = S_{i} + i - 1$

$runningTotal = S_2$

Comment: Oh, this is brilliant. Thank you for widening my intuition. I really appreciate it.
I notice that you didn't add i=12, but rather just 12. I assume this is simply that it's assumed i is the iterator. (thank you to the others who helped answer too)

Comment: The expression rather than stating 77 was to show my working out to someone as it's an expression to give proof of how big something is going to be (and so the 12 and the 2 are noted in the supporting notes I gave them). Thank you once again!

Comment: @Jimmyt1988 Regarding $i=12$ versus $12$, it is just the standard convention to write the name of the index variable only on the subscript of the summation sign, rather than both the subscript and superscript.  It’s analogous to “FOR i = 1 TO 5” in Pascal-style programming languages.

Comment: Love it. Thank you for your help! Thank you thank you.